# Blender 4.0.2 Voronoi Texture OK in Material Preview but not in Rendered

Tags: materials

I have been using the Carvature wood material nodes in 3.6 with great success but in 4.0.2 something interesting happens. The textures preview correctly in Material Preview but not in Rendered view. I tracked the issue down (or so I think) to the Voronoi Texture. Check the difference in these screenshots. The only difference is the Viewport Shading.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I noticed is that when in Rendered View but switching to EEVEE the results are correct. So something to do with Cycles?

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to fix it. Regarding the screenshot below, the *Vector Transform* node was transforming from *Object* to *Object* i.e. not doing anything to the vector. When I changed the transformation from *Object* to *World*, it worked in Cycles and EEVEE.

Curiously,

- *Object* -> *Object* did seem to transform Object -> World in EVEE.
- *Object* -> *Object* did seem to transform *Object* -> *World* in Cycles in Blender 3.6.

[image]